# MOSS 2010 virtual path to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, moss, wsp

I am attempting to host an ASP.NET application inside of my SharePoint site. I want to host a full-application so I'm hoping to run it as a virtual path application.

Following instructions mentioned in other areas around the web, which said that I could go into ISS and create a virtual path inside of my SharePoint site to run the application. 
[Link](http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf) (page 4)

After finishing this portion I began getting asked for credentials. I got rid of the credentials request, by browsing to the folder containing my Virtual Path and changing security settings to allow iUSR_ account. I no longer get credentials, but I now get a blank page.

I don't know how to get passed this blank page issue, any help is greatly appreciated.

Background: I realize that I can run an application in the layouts folder, but it doesn't seem to work the same as it references .cs files that should be in the code-behind.

-Update-

The blank page issue is solved if I convert the virtual path to an application. However, it seems that I can't piggy-back off of the SharePoint's user credentials when it's an application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the AppPool for the MVC site is running as the same user as the sharepoint webapp?

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the reply. The documentation says to create a virtual path. Doesn't my site have to be an application in order to have access to the app pool?